# How to query public facebook events by location or city? v2.8

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am trying to find a way to get public events around me.

It seems that the API is not working properly or I am missing something, because this example is not working for me:

https://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/search?q=concert&type=event&center=-37.784835199999996,175.2793385&distance=300

Comment: You are missing that the documentation explicitly states that center and location are for searching _places_, not events.

Comment: Ohh, so how to search by location?

Comment: You would need to get places in the region first, and then query those pages for their events.